# Как работает hover?

Tags: html, css, hover

```css
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.links{
    font-family: 'Krub', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px;
}
.links :hover{
    color: rgb(0, 64, 255);
}
```

```html
<a href="" id="registLink" class="links">Register</a>
                
                <a href="" id="newPass" class="links">Forgot password?</a>
```

Почему при `hover` цвет не изменяется??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите пробел перед :hover. Просто синтаксическая ошибка.

Comment: ого. А это влияет...